# Simplify expression in SymEngine.jl

Tags: julia, sympy

In [`SymPy.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaPy/SymPy.jl), expressions may be easily simplified using the `simplify` function.

```
julia> using SymPy

julia> expr = x * (3 - 4/x)
  ⎛    4⎞
x⋅⎜3 - ─⎟
  ⎝    x⎠

julia> simplify(expr)
3⋅x - 4
```

However, there seems to be no similar function in [`SymEngine.jl`](https://github.com/symengine/SymEngine.jl).

```
julia> using SymEngine

julia> expr = x * (3 - 4/x)
x*(3 - 4*x^(-1))
```

From what I can tell, `SymEngine` is, by no means, complete. I would still like to be able to simplify my expressions, though. Is there a way I can achieve this, either through either an existing or a custom function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `simplify` yet in SymEngine. There is `expand` though, which can do what you want in this case.

```
julia> expr = x * (3 - 4/x)
x*(3 - 4*x^(-1))

julia> expand(expr)
-4 + 3*x
```

This is similar to SymPy's `expand`